# TFS Build 2015 - Get Capabilities of Build Agents

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am trying to programmatically find the Capabilities of each Build Agent.

I found the Rest-API to list all Build Agents

```
http://[tfsurl]/_apis/distributedtask/pools/[poolid]/agents?api-version=2.3-preview.1
```

But this will only show the basic information of the agent.

Is there a way to get more detailed information on the Agents and its Capabilities ?
Additionally, is there a good page with the REST-API options, i have not able to find above API link in the documentation anywhere, i found it on another SO page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The agent REST API is undocumented, see [REST API Overview for Visual Studio Team Services and Team Foundation Server](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview) for more information.

However you can use tools such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to track the the API, following below steps to get Capabilities of Build Agents with REST API:

1. Get Pool ID :

   `GET http://server:8080/tfs/_apis/distributedtask/pools/`
2. Get Agent ID based on the pool ID :

   `GET http://server:8080/tfs/_apis/distributedtask/pools/39/agents/`
3. Get the Capabilities of the specific Build Agent:

   `GET http://server:8080/tfs/_apis/distributedtask/pools/39/agents/158?includeCapabilities=true`

If you just want to get the information of the Agents and its Capabilities, the simplest way is via the web portal:

1. Go to TFS Home page : `http://server:8080/tfs/_home`
2. Navigate to **Manage Server** (gear icon) > **Agent Pools** > Select a pool > Select the agent > **Capabilities**

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! great reply that will help me.